# No member named 'move' in namespace 'std'

Tags: c++, macos, qt, c++11, macos-sierra

I am trying to create something in Qt Creator and I was using a library that has a requirement on [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) . The issue is that Eigen uses C++11 to compile and my MacOS (running on Sierra and has XCode 8) does not seem to have the latest C++ compiler.

It returns the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/eigen3/Eigen/src/Core/DenseStorage.h:277: error: no member named 'move' in namespace 'std'; did you mean 'modf'?
      : m_data(std::move(other.m_data))
               ~~~~~^~~~
                    modf
```

The compiler says I'm using GCC (in Qt Creator's preferences). Is there another way to fix this? I'm trying to get this running on Qt Creator.

Comment: `#include <utility>`, compile with c++11 at the very least

Comment: How do I force C++11 in QtCreator? The pro file says I've added it. CONFIG += console c++11

Comment: `gcc --version` will tell you exactly which version (and which compiler, probably not actually gcc on macOS) you're actually using. Check the release notes and see if it supports C++11/14 and which flags you need to pass it to enable the support, if any.

Comment: Qt Creator itself doesn't govern that. Add `CONFIG += c++11` or `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += C++11` to your `.pro` file.

Comment: @Anil QtCreator supports different variants of projects, qmake based, CMake based, Makefile etc, so it depends what you use.

Comment: I'm on GCC 4.2.1. I changed the GCC version in my Qt Creator Preferences. Where else do I need to change it?